# Don't want to share session

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, forms-authentication

I have two ASP.net MVC applications say **a.xyz.com/Customer** and **a.xyz.com/CustomerTest**.

I have implemented cookie-based FormsAuthentication. Name of Auth cookie (*AUTH* and *AUTHTEST*) is different in both the Applications. Problem is that when I browse the applications in same browser, Session Cookies are available in both the apps. Also when I Abandon session in one application, second application's session abandons as well.

Both applications are running under same app pool. I cannot change the app Pool as they are having rewrite rules also which will not be available if I change the app pool.

I don't want to share the session between these two applications.

Please let me know if it is possible and How?

Answer (score 0):

It is done.

I have changed the session cookie name of both the Applications in sessionState.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="60"  cookieName="PRODSession" />

<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="60"  cookieName="TestSession" />
```